# Choosing 3 cards and the probability of those outcomes>>

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Three cards are drawn from a deck of 52. Compute the following probabilities:

1. they are 3-of-a-kind, for example 3 aces, or 3 kings;
2. there is a pair among them, but not a 3-of-a-kind;
3. at least one ace occurs in the hand.
4. No ace occurs in the hand.

So this question is just saying that we grab 3 cards at the same time.
I'm stuck on one, but I think its supposed to be (4*13)/(22100) = .00235

Reasoning:
4 is just 4 choose 3 because there are 4 different ways to get a triple of the same card (number/face). and times 13 is for the different (number/face) cards. I divided this by 52 choose 3 to get me my answer. Please let me know if I made any mistakes!

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Your answer to the first question is correct.  Have you attempted the other parts?